# How to utilize the java compiled libraries in python?

Tags: java, python, python-2.7, shared-libraries, jython

I have a java compiled libraries and want to utilize them in python script. What is a best way to go if possible?

Comment: any example of the import statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can use Java libraries in Jython. There is example of using JDBC driver to connect to database and get some info about it:

```
from java.sql import DriverManager

def show_db_info(db_url, usr, passwd, schema_name=None):
    db = DriverManager.getConnection(db_url, usr, passwd)
    dbmi = db.getMetaData()
    ...
```